# how i cant select from mysql without duplication

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is too complex

now i have `files` table

I selected from it the files which added in last seven days. it returns many ids like 1,2,3,4,5 ok
it's great.  Now the problem:

i have `tutorial` table

every `tutorial` has some files of `files` table

now i selected from `files` which last added from 7 days

and make list ordered by files downloaded count desc
and after that I select from `tutorial` which equal tutorial id in the `files` table
this mean

```
files_id tutorial_id
   1          2

files_id tutorial_id
   2          2
```

this mean two files in one tutorial

now the tutorial

```
tut_id tut_title
 1        tite test
```

downloaded in last seven days by files list

```
file_id = 1 this mean tutorial id = 2
file_id = 2 this mean tutorial id = 2
```

This means I have one tutorial and two files in the most downloaded list
will duplicate the tutorial title twice.

its really complex.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what the question is. Could you provide your table layouts, some code samples and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Blimey. Start again, rephrase!

Comment: What you want to show?
Most downloaded files or tutorials?
If first, then result is correct, 'cause you have two files related with one tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you basically want to list the **tutorials** most downloaded versus the **files** most downloaded.

In which case, you can use the following query to get the TOP 10:

```
SELECT tutorials.tut_id,
       tutorials.tut_title,
       MAX(files.file_downloads) AS tut_downloads
  FROM tutorials, tutorial_files, files
  WHERE tutorials.tut_id = tutorial_files.tut_id
    AND files.file_id    = tutorial_files.file_id
  GROUP BY tutorials.tut_id, tutorials.tut_title
  ORDER BY tut_downloads DESC
  LIMIT 10;
```

You can change the `MAX` by a `SUM` depending on how you want to calculate the numbers of downloads per-tutorial.

Same, but limits it to the files added in the last 7 days:

```
SELECT tutorials.tut_id,
       tutorials.tut_title,
       MAX(files.file_downloads) AS tut_downloads
  FROM tutorials, tutorial_files, files
  WHERE tutorials.tut_id = tutorial_files.tut_id
    AND files.file_id    = tutorial_files.file_id
    AND files.file_added >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS)
  GROUP BY tutorials.tut_id, tutorials.tut_title
  ORDER BY tut_downloads DESC
  LIMIT 10;
```

If this is not what you want, I am sorry. Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

[SELECT DISTINCT ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)?

Comment: @Moustafa No offense but your english isn't perfect and it's hard to understand your question. Nowhere do you mention anything about trying SELECT DISTINCT so Dmitry's answer seems valid enough. It would be very helpful if you provided some real sample data, expected data and sample queries that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Limit 1` to get the top most row after ordering. This will return only the first row, which is the most download file (Remember you ordered it, so the most download file will be on top).